# Java File Exception Handling

Tags: java, exception

I am supposed to create a sample program for exception handling for file operations for my java assignment. I am having trouble understanding since I am a C++ guy. It would be really very helpful if somebody could point out the flaw in my code below. I am referring [this](http://www.akadia.com/services/java_exceptions.html) article. Eclipse is giving me *"Unreachable catch block for FileNotFoundException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body"* error.

```
import java.io.*;

public class file {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String arg1 = args[0];
        String arg2 = args[1];
        System.out.println(arg1);
        System.out.println(arg2);
        File f1, f2;

        try {
            f2 = new File(arg2);
            f1 = new File(arg1);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        /*
            if(!f1.exists()) {
                System.out.println(arg1 + " does not exist!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if(!f2.exists()) {
                System.out.println(arg2 + " does not exist!");
                System.exit(0);
            }


            if(f1.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println(arg1 + " is a Directory!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if(f2.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println(arg2 + " is a Directory!");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            if(!f1.canRead()) {
                System.out.println(arg1 + " is not readable!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if(!f2.canRead()) {
                System.out.println(arg2 + " is not readable!");
                System.exit(0);
            }*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In future, please include the code in your question.

Comment: Please also read more thoroughly about Java `checked` and `unchecked` expections. The first ones inherit from `Exception` class the latter ones from `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Look at the docs for the [`File` constructor you're calling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29). The *only* exception it's declared to throw is `NullPointerException`. Therefore it *can't* throw `FileNotFoundException`, which is why you're getting the error. You can't try to catch a checked exception which the compiler can prove is never thrown within the corresponding `try` block.

Creating a `File` object doesn't check for its existence. If you were *opening* the file (e.g. with `new FileInputStream(...)` then *that* could throw `FileNotFoundException`... but not just creating a `File` object.

Comment: Thank You guys!
OK now what should i do if i want to throw all those exceptions i mentioned in the code?

Comment: @CAD_coding: What do you mean? Your code doesn't try to throw any exceptions.

Comment: @JonSkeet i want to throw filenotfoundexception, eofexception, objectstreamexception, ioexception.
found them here:
http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/12/04/exceptions.html

Comment: @Jagger actually the commented portion will be in the catch for filenotfoundexception. I want the user to know why exactly the file was not found.

Comment: @CAD_coding: If you want to throw them yourself, you can do so. Alternatively, you could do something which would throw the exception itself - such as opening a `FileInputStream` with the relevant file.

Comment: @JonSkeet  & jagger, so you mean that i dont need to code the commented portion? So when the filenotfoundexception is thrown, how do i find the exact cause of the exception?

Comment: @CAD_coding: Well the stack trace will show you which line it's thrown on, across the stack. It's *still* not really clear what you're trying to do, or how much you understand.

Comment: @JonSkeet what i want is that, if the user gives the path of a folder then after the exception is catched i want to println("This is a folder") so that the user knows why the exception was fired. I hope you are getting what i meant...

Comment: @CAD_coding What you need in this case is just checking whether the file is a directory using [`isDirectory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory()) method. If it is a directory print what you need to print.

Comment: @CAD_coding: But there's no exception to catch - what are you trying to do to provoke the exception? You can test for the name being a directory without any exceptions at all...

Comment: hmmm OK.
was just trying to fit the code to satisfy my teachers requirement for exceptions.
Anyways thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the constructor of class [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) with one argument

```
public File(String pathname)  
Parameters:pathname - A pathname string Throws: NullPointerException - If the pathname argument is null
Throws: NullPointerException - If the pathname argument is null
```

throws only one exception and that is `NullPointerException`. Your code tries to catch a `FileNotFoundException` which is not related to `NullPointerException` and this is why you get this error in Eclipse.

One way to go is to catch exceptions of class `Exception` which is the `super` class of all exceptions in Java. Another way is to catch all the exceptions (each in different `catch` block) that the invoked construct throws (which can be easily obtained by going through its API). The third approach is to catch only the exceptions (again which are actually thrown by the construct) that make sense to your application and ignore the others.